# Hint on finding the limit of this function

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $10^{2011}$, then:

$$\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} p(x)e^{x} = ?$$

How do I even begin with this? I tried expressing it into a form where L'Hospital rule is applicable, but found that it cannot be expressed as such. Tried taking logarithm but failed there as well. So how do I find its limit. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: It is $\pm \infty$ depending on whether the highest degree term is positive or negative.

Comment: So my limit would be $+$ or $-$  $\infty$, right? But the answer given is $0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If the answer given is 0, it sounds like there’s a missing minus sign in the exponential.  Then you can L’Hopital it 10^{2011} times; the numerator gets reduced and the exp(x) in the denominator stays fixed.

Comment: Thank you @evanb. I was suspicious of the same.